# Power shell send email in loop and write output to file

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2

```
Send-MailMessage -From "test@xxx.com" -To "aaa@xxx.com","bbb@xxx.com","ccc@xxx.com","ddd@xxx.com" -SmtpServer "xx.xx.xx.xx" -Subject "Test email subject" -Body "Test email body"
```

I want to write a script using above command in loop say 100 times and run every 2 seconds and write an output to a log file which later can be used for analysis.

Issue: My severer gives intermittent issue while sending emails. I want to see logs to see how many emails go through out of 100 and how many failed and with what error message.

Comment: Can your email host process 400 messages or more in less than two (2) seconds? Or, is that what you are trying to determine?

Answer (score 0):

Running multiple times would require some sort of loop. A [`for`](https://ss64.com/ps/for.html) loop seems most appropriate for each loop of 100, and a [`while`](https://ss64.com/ps/while.html) loop seems appropriate for looping over each set.

Since you are running commands very quickly you will want some sort of parallelism. Jobs, Runspaces, and workflows are the three most common forms. Jobs are the easiest to work with but the least efficient.

Then the `Start-Sleep` command can be used for the delay between trials.

There are many ways to write out to a file, `Out-File -Append` is one way. `Try\catch` can be used to catch the errors and output those to the log as well.

```
$Iterations = 100
$Delay = 2
$StopTime = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(5)
$Command = {Send-MailMessage -From "test@xxx.com" -To "aaa@xxx.com","bbb@xxx.com","ccc@xxx.com","ddd@xxx.com" -SmtpServer "xx.xx.xx.xx" -Subject "Test email subject" -Body "Test email body"}


while ((Get-Date -le $StopTime)) {
    try {
        Remove-Job -State Completed
        for ($i = 0; $i -lt $Iterations; $i++) {
            Start-Job -ScriptBlock $command
        }
        "Jobs created at (Get-Date)" | Out-File "C:\example\log.txt" -Append
        Start-Sleep $delay
    }
    catch {
        $error[0] | Out-File "C:\example\log.txt" -Append
    }
}
```